# Linking two structures in C

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to link 2 structures, one is a matrix and one is a single node. The connection should be a matrix that holds size and an array of rows with nodes connected between each other:
so a 3X3 matrix should look like this:

|Node|->|Node|->|Node|-> NULL

|Node|->|Node|->|Node|-> NULL

|Node|->|Node|->|Node|-> NULL

The question is how do I connect it properly?
Do I need to allocate the memory for the rows only or should I allocate the memory for all elemets and then connect them?

```
typedef struct cellNode {
        int cell;
        struct cellNode* next;
}   Node;

typedef struct  {
        int numRows;
        int numColumns;
        Node** rows;
}   Matrix;



Matrix* MatrixAdder(int row, int col, char mat)
{
    Matrix temp=NULL;
    int i,j;
    if(!(temp=(Matrix*)malloc(sizeof(Matrix)));
        exit(1);
    temp->numRows=row;
    temp->numColumns=col;
    if (!(temp.rows[i]=(Node*)malloc((row)*sizeof(Node))));
        exit (1);
    printf("Please insert values for matrix %c:\n",mat);
    for (i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        if(!(temp->rows[i]=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node))))
            exit (1);
        printf("Enter row %d data\n",i);
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&temp->rows->cell);
            temp->rows=temp->rows->next;
            if(!(temp->rows=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node))))
              exit (1);
        }
        temp->rows=NULL;
    }


}
```

Comment: Using a linked list for a matrix is a little odd, normally it would be an array of arrays or similar. Why are you using linked lists? Is it part of a school assignment or similar?

Comment: Your code is harder to read than necessary. Consider using spaces.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes its for a course :( I think its odd as well but need to do it anyway like that. any suggestions ?

Comment: @jarmod sorry about that, will do.

Comment: Do you have a clear statement of what the `MatrixAdder` function is supposed to do, or more generally of the exercise itself? Your description isn't particularly precise.

Comment: @jarmod MatrixAdder returns a complete user filled matrix to the main function via pointer.

Comment: This is not a good design of the data structure because it has two `numColums` and the number of links in your `cellNode` that do the same thing and will have to be carefully synchronized in practice. If the data structure is fixed, I'd recommend setting `next` to null always or just not using `numColumns`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how many nodes you need to allocate, then you can of course allocate them all in a single call to `malloc` (as a normal plain "dynamic array" of nodes) and then link them all together. All you need is to keep track of the pointer returned by `malloc`.

But you still need to allocate the array of pointers used for `rows`. So no matter what you need at least two allocations.

It could be dome something like this (using normal variables and not your structures):

```
int numRows = 3;
int numColumns = 3;

// Allocate all the nodes
Node *allNodes = malloc(sizeof *allNodes * numRows * numColumns);

// Allocate the array of pointers needed
Node **rows = malloc(sizeof *rows * numRows);

// Initialize the rows
for (int row = 0; row < numRows; ++row)
{
    // if numColums == 3 then for
    //   row == 0 get a pointer to allNodes[0]
    //   row == 1 get a pointer to allNodes[3]
    //   row == 2 get a pointer to allNodes[6]
    rows[row] = &allNodes[row * numColumns];
}

// Now create the linked lists
for (int row = 0; i < numRows; ++row)
{
    // For numRows == 3, this will make node point to, in turn:
    //   allNodes[0]
    //   allNodes[3]
    //   allNodes[6]
    Node **node = &rows[row];

    // node will be pointing to a pointer to the *previous* node
    // So start with 1 because that's then the *next* node in the list
    for (int col = 1; col < numColumns; ++col)
    {
        // When row == 0 then:
        //   When col == 1 then link allNodes[0]->next to allNodes[1]
        //   When col == 2 then link allNodes[1]->next to allNodes[2]
        // When row == 1 then:
        //   When col == 1 then link allNodes[3]->next to allNodes[4]
        //   When col == 2 then link allNodes[4]->next to allNodes[5]
        // Etc...
        (*node)->next = &allNodes[row * numColumns + col];
        (*node) = &(*node)->next;
    }

    // Now head will be pointing to the lasts nodes next member
    (*node) = NULL;
}
```

<sub>[Note: Code not tested!]</sub>

When finished you only have two pointers to free:

```
free(rows);
free(allNodes);
```

---

To understand exactly what's going on, if you're having trouble following along, I recommend you use a debugger together with a pen and some paper.

First of all draw a long rectangle for `allNodes` and divide it into `numRows * numColumns` number of sub-rectangles. Label them with their index (so the first becomes `0`, the second `1` etc.). Then draw a second rectangle for `rows` and divide it into `numRows` sub-rectangles. Label these too with the indexes.

Now as you step along in the debugger, draw arrows between the sub-rectangles for form "pointers". For example with the first iteration of the first loop you draw an arrow from `rows[0]` to `allNodes[0]`.

For the second loop, where the linked lists are created, draw another little rectangle and label it `head`. For each iteration of the outer linking loop you (erase) and draw an arrow from `head` to first `rows[0]`, and so on.

Inside the inner linking loop (over columns) with the statement

```
(*head)->next = &allNodes[row * numColumns + col];
```

start at `head` and follow its arrow to `rows`. Then again follow the arrow to `allNodes`, and *continue* to follow any arrows until there are no more. Then draw an arrow from that element in `allNodes` to the next element in `allNodes` as indicated by `row * numColumns + col`. So for the first iteration you follow the arrow from `head` to `rows[0]`, you follow that along to `allNodes[0]` where you draw an arrow to `allNodes[1]`.

To understand why we use a pointer to a pointer for `node` and what `(*node) = NULL` is doing, then we need to draw how it looks like after the inner loop finishes. Again we use `row == 0` as example.

```
+------+     +------------------+
| node | --> | allNodes[2].next | --> ???
+------+     +------------------+
```

By dereferencing `node` (as in `(*node)`) then we get to `allNodes[2].next` which we then can assign to be a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: You could `malloc` all at once by using addition, but you have to be careful the alignment of the pointers. Could be cache-friendlier?